# Sci-fi book series with a Concorde-like spaceship on the cover of at least one of the books?

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship

The main character is the pilot who somehow picks up a symbiotic organism that helps him through many situations. (I vividly remember one episode where he needs to play a pipe for hours on end to mesmerize a bunch of giant spiders)

The ship is owned by either a wealthy person or a research organization. They go from planet to planet doing research. One of the other characters is a young girl who happens to be very intelligent.

I used to have the series in paperback years ago and lost them during one of my numerous house moves.

Comment: When was 'years ago' :) and any idea when the series might have been published.

Comment: Half my science fiction novels have Concorde like spaceships on the covers.

Comment: Hi there. I would have read these some time between 1975 and 1985. I believe that the series was recent at that time. It was at a time when I was reading 3-4 books a week on the train ride to work. Remember e

Comment: The spaceship design was reminiscent of Serenity from Firefly - at least in the nose/cockpit area anyway

Comment: There is a Doctor Who book with an actual Concorde on the cover. The least said about the actual story the better, though.

Comment: This is so weird that you’re looking for the same thing I am. For some reason this image popped into my head from when I was a kid. It was a strong emotional response which surprised me. I began searching and came upon your question. I have been racking my brain and the closest I can come is something called “far traveler” or Something like that. It was a long time ago and I will continue searching but I’m glad to know it does exist in someone else’s mind. If I find it I’ll let you know.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the Swan Songs series by Brian Stableford. From the "SF Site":The main character, Grainger, is everything the heroes of the 30s space operas were not. After surviving shipwreck on a remote planet where he picks up a symbiotic inner-voice entity, Grainger, to pay off the costs of his rescue, must indenture himself as the pilot of an untried new research starship, the Hooded Swan. He's doesn't give a rat's ass about the glory of his home world or of his "employer's" goals to collect alien technologies and knowledge, which send him, reluctantly, all over the known universe and other places besides, gathering up information or artefacts.
The first novel Halcyon Drift's cover has a very Serenity like ship on the cover

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Three of the four others in the series. Art for all by Angus McKie. In fact the art for Promised Land was also used on a 1978 Vanglis album called Hypothesis.

Comment: Probably should have just edited the extra cover shots into the existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

***[The Far Traveler](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7956644-the-far-traveler)*** (1977) by A. Bertram Chandler, the first book in the *[John Grimes: Far Traveller Couriers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76647-john-grimes-far-traveller-couriers)* series.

From Goodreads:

> The Far Traveler was a rich woman's toy constructed of gold and directed by an omniscient, dictatorial, and feminine computer known as Big Sister. John Grimes had become the vessel's captain and sets off to look for lost space colonies.

I think this is what you are referring to.

[image: Book cover]